# Use full ISO-690 capitalisation style in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I'm using a biber backend with a minimal example repo trying to replicate the formal guidelines that my university institute imposes on me.

They require ISO-690 citations, in particular `LASTNAME Firstname` capitalisation everywhere.

I am aware of the `iso-authoryear` style which does pretty much what I need, except in footnotes. We are required to cite using footnotes in a `verbose-ibid` fashion, but the footnotes do not keep the `LASTNAME` capitalisation unfortunately.

Minimal TeX code:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=iso-authoryear,
    citestyle=verbose-ibid,
    abbreviate=false,
    block=space,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    autolang=other
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{How to quote}
Direct quotes are very useful if done right according to the guidelines of my institute.\footcite{muster:quellen}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@Book{muster:quellen,
  title     = {Der Sinn von Quellenangaben. Eine unkritische Auseinandersetzung},
  publisher = {Testverlag},
  year      = {2014},
  author    = {Mustermann, Max},
  address   = {Berlin},
}
```

This yields the following example when compiling with `lualatex`:
[image]

How can I achieve a setting of `MUSTERMANN, Max` (and similar capitalisation for other authors) **even in the footnote**?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the "BibTeX" tag to "biblatex".

Comment: @Mico Yes indeed, I was a bit sloppy with the suggested tags. Thank you for paying attention to the details :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`biblatex-iso690` uses the internal command `\lastnameformat` (which will probably be renamed to `\familynameformat` soon, so if the answer ceases to work, try `\familynameformat` in the code below instead) to format the family name in the bibliography. If you want the name format to apply almost everywhere, try

```
\documentclass[english,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=iso-authoryear,
    citestyle=verbose-ibid,
    abbreviate=false,
    autolang=other
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily{\lastnameformat}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: SIGFRIDSSON, Emma; RYDE, Ulf, 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry. Vol. 19, no. 4, S. 377–395. Abgerufen unter DOI: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works like a charm! Where can I read up on those `\mkbibnamefamily`-style commands? I want to learn how to make fixes like these myself, but the documentation seems a little "overkill" for finding specific detail information like this…

Comment: @suushiemaniac `\mkbibnamefamily` is documented in the `biblatex` manual (p. 289 in v3.14), but in order to know what to do in the first place it is usually quickest to just check the source code of the style. The `biblatex` manual for the most parts documents only the `biblatex` core and some higher-level bits of the standard styles. If you are using a custom style, you can try and check back with its documentation, but usually they don't contain elaborate explanations about additional possible modifications that go beyond the style they implement.